# Have a UPC scanner submit to a script automatically over a network

Tags: linux, bash, apache, networking, centos

I have a barcode scanner that reads barcodes coming down a manufacturing line, and then will send the read UPC to an IP:port as an I/O device over ethernet.

Initially, the people who built this anticipate that you will have a windows machine with a controller open writing the scans to a text file. I'm not sure how that's useful to anyone, but I digress. The system works essentially as a keyboard, that spits out to an open port.

I would like to be able to trigger a script once the return key is detected. I am running rhel fedora centos 8, and I assume that I can set up a bash that is called by something listening to a port.

I'm a software dev, and server configuration is not what I normally work with. After a lot of googling I'm still unsure of the following:

- which listener is best for this use case, so I can narrow my search? I've found the socat command, but don't fully understand it.
- if I'm using socat, or any listener, for that matter, how do i tell it to stop and submit to a script on return? how does it know when the message has ended?
- can i tell it to call a PHP file? i need to store these reads to a database, and PHP is already on the server, so that seems like the simplest choice.

Thanks for any help you can provide. I just need some basics so I can fine tune my google search. A lot of what comes back is setting up port 80 through Apache, and the searches are just flooded with red herrings.

Comment: This seems to be a unidirectional implementation and so netcat (the nc command) should suffice as opposed to socat. The traffic on a given host/port can then be written to a log file and a script used to parse this log file and write the data to a database. Question still arise around the frequency of data received and how frequently/timely the database needs to updated

Comment: That sounds perfect. I'm not familiar with how Linux handles files, but the scanner would essentially be running 24/7. If a PHP script opens the file to read from it, during that split second it is open, will the file be locked for writing for the scanner?

Comment: I'm not sure what database you are using but this may give you some ideas - https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006377154-Using-Netcat-for-large-MySQL-database-imports

Comment: We have a lot of options on databases. Your link is handy though, as I believe I'll be using  MySQL on this one. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pipe the output of netcat directly to a script (in your favorite language) that reads and processes tha data.

```
# example: listen on port 12345 and wait for new connection if connection is closed
nc -lk 12345 | while IFS= read -r line
do
  # do something with $line
  printf '%s\n' "$line"
done
```

This script assumes that the device sends text data that can be processed line by line. If the device sends windows line endings you might have to strip the CR.

You might also need some error handling, e.g. restart the whole command if something fails.

**Edit:**

This answer further assumes that the scanner uses a TCP connection to send the data and handles a single connection at a time.
When the script cannot read and process the data as fast as it is sent, at some point the send queue will be full and the sending operation should be blocked. This depends on the implementation in the scanner. (The scanner's manual may tell details.)

In case the scanner uses UDP instead of TCP, netcat can handle this as well with `nc -ul 12345`. With UDP, if the receiver cannot process the data fast enough, packets will get lost.

As mentioned in https://serverfault.com/q/207683, there seem to be slightly different implementations of netcat. So you might have to check the command line syntax of your version.

**2nd edit:**

**I guess the processing time will not be a problem.**

Think about the amount of data that will be coming in.

- How many codes will be scanned per minute or per second?
- How many characters are stored in a code?

I guess it is a fairly small amount in total.

And check the performace of your processing and/or database.

- For example, write a script that stores hard-coded or random data in your database similar to data from the scanner. How many data records can it store per minute/second?

I guess the script will be able to process much more data than the scanner will send.

**In my opinion the more difficult part is the stability of the system as a whole if it is expected to run permanently and if the function is critical for your business.**

The implementation should be able to detect and handle all sorts of possible problems and try to recover. (hanging connection, hanging commands/programs, invalid data, database access errors, restarting the program after unexpected termination, ...)

Is it necessary to detect a missing or lost connection from the scanner?

What will happen in case of data loss. (e.g. a missed scan) Is it required / possible to detect this?

In contrast to using a tool like netcat, you might have more control over all the details if you implement the server yourself.

Comment: This is a great help! This is maybe a dumb question, but does the queue stack? I don't have (nor do I want) a way to halt the upcs going by, so they'll just keep sending them. While it's waiting on an open connection will second third etc connections queue up or crash (I can Google it tomorrow, np if you're not sure of default behavior)

Comment: @ClaytonEngle This script handles a single connecction at a time. If the script processes the data slower than the scanner sends it, then at some point the send queue will be full and sending data should be blocked. (Depends on the implementation in the scanner.) Please add more details to the question how the communication of the scanner works. Does it use a TCP connection? (what I assumed for my answer) Does it keep a single connection to send data of subsequent scans or does it open and close the connection for a every scan? Maybe add a link to a manaual that contains this information.

Comment: Great. I'll just make sure it has its own dedicated VM to handle it. Thank you!

Comment: @ClaytonEngle Using a separate VM might be overkill, and a VM may require more resources than running this little program on the host. Additional information as I already requested might allow me or someone else to give a more detailed answer. Depending on the information it might even be necessary to modify my answer.

Comment: Well, to clarify, we don't yet have the hardware to play with, and we've only been able to interact with a young salesman who isn't sure of technical specifications. Our assumption is similar to yours though, that it is TCP. In this line of comments I was more asking if the default behavior of linux is that the script would be locked until it completes, if it's awaiting an open connection. As for overkill, that is A-OK. We have a lot of server time available, very few employees using it, and this will be a critical process. I will likely stash other bashed processes on it as well some day.

Comment: And I should say, I'll probably have another better question once I have it, but what you and Raman have provided is enough to get the scanner storing something, hopefully, and from there I can dig a lot deeper.

Comment: @ClaytonEngle I added a few more suggestions what you should consider.

Comment: Amazingly, your comments led down a rabbit hole. I ended up being able to create a PHP script that hooks into my Laravel API to handle many of the troubles you've outlined. I'm now looking into a process to monitor the socket server and to keep it up and running if it stops listening. Likely creating a daemon for that... Hope that's the right thing to do haha.